# pip .local/lib "Permission denied"

Tags: permissions, pip

I have been trying to get ipython installed, and, using pip, I did a local user install to ~/.local/.  This had some trouble, and I wasn't sure if my python path was set correctly in order to find it.  But one that is weird, to me, is that my ~/.local/lib directory cannot be accessed.  When I try to cd into it, I get "Permission Denied":

```
me@localhost:.local$cd lib/
bash: cd: lib/: Permission denied
```

I do not have the same problem with the other subfolders of .local.

FYI, I am doing this on an installation of trusty on an Acer chromebook with xfce4.  Things are otherwise working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A the command below in your terminal

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":"$USER" ~/.local/lib
```

If that is not enough, even this command (note the uppercase X)

```
sudo chmod -R +X ~/.local/lib
```

---

from `man chown`

```
NAME
       chown - change file owner and group
```

from `man chmod`

```
execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission
for some user (X)
```

Comment: Yup, that did it.